# Como puedo contar los caracteres que yo elija en una cadena

Tags: java, string, eclipse

En el ejercicio me piden que el usuario inserte una cadena de texto y un caracter con el que despues digamos cuantos hay en esa cadena de texto, ¿Cómo cuento los caracteres que hay?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal_5_4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

        //Dada una cadena cad, y un caracter car, verificar cuántas veces se repite el carácter car en la cadena cad.


        //variables
        String cadena= "";
        char character= ' ';
        int contador=0;

        System.out.println("Inserte una cadena de caracteres: ");
        cadena=teclado.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Inserte el caracter que quieres contar: ");
        character= teclado.next().charAt(0);

        for(int i=0 ; i<cadena.length(); i++) {

            if (i==character) 
                contador++;
            {
                System.out.println("Hay " + contador + " caracteres " + character);


            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, creo que no entendiste mi problema, en el ejercicio me manda pedirle al usuario una cadena de caracteres y despues un caracter solo, y despues contar todos los caracteres que nosotros pusimos en la cadena de caracter (ej: la cadena es: Hola que tal estas  --- el caracter que elijo es "a" y el ordenador me tiene que decir "hay 3 caracteres que tu elejiste" ). No se si asi se entiende mejor

Comment: No puedes usar `i==character`, puesto que `i` es un número (la posición en la que te encuentras). Esto no falla porque java al comparar un `char` con un `int` te hace una conversión automagicamente y compara el número con el valor en ASCII del `char` (65 para la "A", por ejemplo), pero como has comprobado tampoco sirve para contar :) Para que te funcione, en vez de comparar con el `i` directamente, utiliza la función `charAt(i)` de String y veras que funciona. Por lo demás, tu bucle debería funcionar correctamente una vez cambiada la comprobación!

Comment: No entiendo muy bien como insertar el `charAt(i)`, si me lo puedes poner en el codigo para verlo y comprenderlo lo agradeceria :).

Comment: Literalmente, `cadena.charAt(i) == character`

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo usar un metodo para ello,que reciba como parámetro la frase y el carácter aunque  puedes realizarlo en el método main,el metodo que te comparto realiza lo que tu ejercicio requiere,debes usar el for para para que recorra la frase que le pases como parámetro y en cada iteracion de i ,compararlo con el carácter elegido y usar el contador para que aumente cada vez que este encuentre similitud

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContarCaracter{

 public static int contarCaracter(String word, char letter){
        int counter = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) 
        {
            if(word.charAt(i) == letter)
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
          return counter;
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);


System.out.println("Ingrese cadena de texto");
String cadena=teclado.nextLine();
System.out.println("Ingrese un caracter");
char caracater=teclado.nextLine().charAt(0);

System.out.println("\nLa cantida de veces que aparece el caracter "+caracater+" en la frase es :"+contarCaracter(cadena,caracater));


 }

}
```